# Getting metadata from links using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, beautifulsoup, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to scrape links to get the title, description, and image to give a small overview of the article or webpage. Currently I have og:title by getting the meta property through BeautifulSoup. This works fine for news articles.

```
if tag.get("property", None) == "og:title":       
        scraper.title = tag.get("content", None)
```

However, [links for an Amazon Echo for example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01K9KW9A4), don't pull any images or product title. How can I go about doing this using BeautifulSoup and Python and pulling the first image found and the title from any website -- maybe not just one supported by opengraph?

Answer (score 1):

[unicontent](https://github.com/hboisgibault/unicontent)  is a library trying to achieve that. It will get the opengraph tags or the HTML tags, or other types of tags. I don't think it can get the first image inside the page though.